# ios Navigation can't pass value to next Viewcontroller when I popViewController again

Tags: ios, navigation

I have two ViewController (ViewController, ResultViewController).

There have three button in the ViewController,and there have a back button in ResultViewController.

In the ResultViewController I want to get the value from the ViewController passing.

So I add the below code in the **ResultViewController**

```
 @interface ResultViewController : UIViewController
 - (IBAction)backEvent:(id)sender;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultLb;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *selectedVal;
 @end
```

.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
     self.resultLb.text = self.selectedVal;

 }
 - (IBAction)backEvent:(id)sender {
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
 }
```

In the **ViewController** have three button action:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
     rvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ResultViewController"];

 }
 - (IBAction)passAEvent:(id)sender {
     rvc.selectedVal = @"A";
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:NO];
 }

 - (IBAction)passBEvent:(id)sender {
     rvc.selectedVal = @"B";
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:NO];
 }

 - (IBAction)passCEvent:(id)sender {
     rvc.selectedVal = @"C";
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:NO];
 }
```

When I first click the button A, that can correct pass the "A" value to the ResultViewController.

But when I click the back button in the ResultViewController.

Then click the B or C button action, that still pass the "A" value.

I see the log, that was not enter B, C event.

I try to run again program, when I click the first button with B button, It was correct enter and pass "B" value to ResultViewController.

But when I click the back button, then click the A or C button, it was not correct value in the ResultViewController.It still show "B" value.

I don't know why? how can I resolve the problem if not use delegate or notify?

Thank you.

[image]

----- edit ----

To the @Gaurav Singh

[image]

I am not find the option about the animate .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're keeping a strong reference to the UIViewController, via your variable `rvc`.

You're setting the value of `resultLb` in the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller. When you push the view controller onto the stack, your view controller's setting the label by taking what's stored in it's variable `selectedVal`.

When you pop the view controller from the stack, because you've got it stored in a variable, it won't get unloaded from memory. It still exists. You may be setting `selectedVal` again when tapping the second button, however `viewDidLoad` isn't going to get run again, as it's not getting re-instantiated.

What you could do is overload `setSelectedVal` on `ResultViewController` as follows:

```
- (void)setSelectedVal:(NSString *)selectedVal {
    _selectedVal = selectedVal;
    self.resultLb.text = selectedVal;
}
```

This way, when you set `selectedVal` from the calling view controller, the above method will be run, setting the value of your property in `ResultViewController`, whilst also modifying your label.

**EDIT - Better still**:

Rather than setting the value of the label in `viewDidLoad:`, do it in `viewWillAppear:` instead. This way, you don't need to override any setters or anything like that. When `viewWillAppear` is called, it'll read the string you've set and set the label's text accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you ,John Rogers. The method is Ok~

Comment: If you've found your solution, please mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are just making it complex. I would do it like this:

1. First I will connect create a storyboard segue from ViewController to Result Controller (View Controller to View Controller segue) and assign a suitable identifier to that segue (say "resultSegue")
2. then following code would work

   ```
   - (IBAction)passAEvent:(id)sender {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"resultSegue" sender:@"A"];
   }

   - (IBAction)passBEvent:(id)sender {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"resultSegue" sender:@"B"];
   }

   - (IBAction)passCEvent:(id)sender {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"resultSegue" sender:@"C"];
   }

   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
            sender:(id)sender {
         if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"resultSegue"]){
             ResultViewController *rvc = segue.destinationViewController;
             rvc.selectedVal = sender; //Here SENDER will have value: A,B or C which we have passed in performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: method
         }
   }
   ```

**Edit:** code in prepareForSegue:sender: method modified so that it check the segue identifier before working on destinationViewController

Comment: I have ever use performSegueWithIdentifier, but when I use the performSegueWithIdentifier, I can't set the navigation animated to NO. So I use the pushViewController instead.

Comment: You can easily do that from storyboard. There used to be an option with segue on storyboard that if we want the push be animated or not

Comment: Sorry, I am not find the animate option in the inspector at Storyboard Segue block.@@

Comment: This will work, but that's not really the intended use of the *sender* parameter. Typically, in the UIKit framework, *sender* is used to describe the object sending the message (the caller), for example *sender* on an IBAction is typically a UIButton.

Comment: @JohnRogers I know, but I find it convenient to pass values that way as long as it don't break the segue.

Comment: @Gaurav Singh, you can see my edit. I am not find the animate option. And thank you response me question.

Comment: @dickfala Ok. You can use custom UIStoryboard segue class.  http://trentmilton.com/push-segue-without-animation.html

Comment: @dickfala You can also add different animation effects by sub classing UIStoryboard segue. I have used it in one of my app to perform a different animation on push.

Comment: @Gaurav Singh, if I custom the segue about without the animation, I need implement the push method?

Comment: @dickfala No!. You have to pick "custom" from segue type and assign it a Segue class. You can find many articles about custom segues on the web.

Answer (score 0):

put

```
rvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ResultViewController"];
```

in `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should give the segue an "id",like "resultSegue".
Then, use the code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
     sender:(id)sender
{
     if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"resultSegue"]){
      ResultViewController *rvc = segue.destinationViewController;
      rvc.selectedVal.text = someUILabel.text;
than use the  [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:NO];//.........
}
```

I will give you more detail when I m at home, if you don`t solve the problem....
Thanks!